# What is the deal with the Godox flash/transmitter hotshoe breaking all the time? How do I fix it?

Tags: sony, godox, hotshoe, foot

I've had the hotshoe on my Godox flash for my Sony camera break multiple times now, and I'm getting sick of having to continually replace the foot assembly. What is up with this and how do I get a permanent fix?

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not a hotshoe on a flash, it's a ***foot***. I know; everybody on youtube (including Robert Hall) and Godox, B&H, and Adorama all refer to it as a "hotshoe", but the hotshoe is the part on the camera. It's hot if it communicates electronically, it's cold if it doesn't. And flash *foot* goes into a shoe.

Basically, Godox sourced or manufactured their Sony multi-interface foot assemblies so that they have two issues.

First, there's an internal plastic part that's brittle and breaks easily, even under regular use without any hard knocks. If you search around, all the complaints about broken foot assemblies on Godox gear is limited solely to Sony users. Nobody else sees this issue.

Secondly, the foot assembly Godox used was too deep for newer E-mount bodies (say, the A7 IV and later models) where Sony made the new hotshoes shallower to get a snugger fit. So, sometimes Godox gear requires more force than expected to get it to seat properly in the newer hotshoe.

A fix arrived in mid-2023: a new Godox for-Sony foot assembly. The newer "metal" shoe vs. the older plastic one. This does not refer to the inner structure of the foot, so much as the easy way to visually identify the difference: the composition of the foot plate:

[image: Godox Sony foot assemblies; old/plastic on left; new/metal on right]

V1-S/V860 III-S/TT685 II-S foot assemblies: L. old/plastic foot; R. new "metal" foot.

The newer metal foot assembly fits the new hotshoes better and is more sturdy and less prone to breakage.

You can purchase the foot assembly for the speedlights. But foot assemblies for the transmitters are not readily available, and you may have to [DIY a solution from a V1-S foot assembly](https://www.reddit.com/r/Godox/comments/zvihnx/replacing_plastic_hot_shoe_in_sony_speedlight_and/).

Newer copies of at least the Xpro II-S transmitter are now shipping with the newer metal foot assembly as well as of late 2023/early 2024.

Comment: There have been some Godox flashes for Canon EOS long ago that also had feet notorious for breaking, though those issues seem to have been resolved before Godox even ventured into the Sony flash game.

Comment: @MichaelC this is a different level of fragility. Anecdotally, the Godox Sony MI foot can break *under regular use without any impact* at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm remembering Yongnuo, rather than Godox, from 15 years or so ago? Back around 2008-10 or so. Everyone was selling replacement feet for them because they would break just by tightening the collar too snug onto the hot shoe.